# Удаление из вектора элементов, индексы которых находятся в другом векторе

Tags: c++

Имеется `vector<float>xp` и `vector<float>jndex`, в котором хранятся отобранные индексы первого вектора. Из первого вектора нужно удалить элементы, индекс которых хранится в `vector<float>xp`
На данный момент код выглядит так:

```
int q=0;

vector<float>xt;
if (!jndex.empty()){
for (int m=0;m<jndex[jndex.size()-1];m++)
{
    if (m!=jndex[q])
    {
        xt.emplace_back(xp[m]);
        yt.emplace_back(yp[m]);
        zt.emplace_back(zp[m]);
    }
    else
    {
        q+=1;
    }
}}

xt.insert(xt.end(),std::make_move_iterator(xp.begin()+jndex[jndex.size()-1]),std::make_move_iterator(xp.end()));
```

На данный момент в `xt` только элементы, добавленные с помощью `insert`, где ошибка в логике?

Comment: ничего не понятно  что есть что

Comment: первый элемент  jndex какое значение имеет? И  что вы пытались делать в последней строкес  move_iterator ами?

Comment: индексы храните в типе  float?...

Answer (score 1):

Откровенно говоря, в вашем коде не увидел ничего похожего на решение поставленной задачи. В ответе @KamilGainutdinov увидел две неприятности - проход по длинному вектору данных вместо короткого вектора индексов, и возможные неприятности при больших значениях индексов, когда эти элементы уже перенесены.

Вариантов вижу несколько. Все требуют отсортированности вектора индексов.
И, само собой, считаем, что все индексы корректны и дублирования индексов нет.

1. Копирование в новый вектор того, что должно остаться. Минус - лишняя память.
2. Удаление путем смещения элементов на освобождающиеся места. Проходим вектору индексов, встретив очередной, переходим к этому элементу, выполняем смещение всех последующих элементов влево, и уменьшение всех оставшихся элементов вектора индексов на 1, и повторяем процедуру. Минус - при очень большом векторе данных слишком много пересылок.
3. Метод @KamilGainutdinov, только несколько модернизированный - *идти нужно от старших индексов*, тогда не может оказаться так, что элемент, который нужно переносить, уже удален. Минус - теряется относительная упорядоченность исходного массива.

Думаю, что такого описания для написания кода достаточно? Или нужно развернуть описание в код?

Вот пример третьего варианта:

```
vector<double> xp {
    0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5,
    0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0, 1.1 };

vector<size_t> idxs {0, 1, 4, 7, 10, 11 };

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    size_t avail = xp.size()-1;
    for(auto i = idxs.rbegin(); i != idxs.rend(); ++i)
    {
        size_t id = *i;
        if (id < avail) swap(xp[id],xp[avail]);
        --avail;
    }
    xp.erase(xp.begin()+avail+1,xp.end());

    for(auto d: xp) cout << d << endl;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Как уже заметили индексы необходимы целочисленные .
Можно попробовать пройтись по вектору один раз , копируя заместо ненужных элементов последующие , помня смещение . Затем просто укоротить хвост вектора.

```
std::vector <float> data;  // массив данных
std::vector <int> indexes; // индексы элементов которые нужно стереть

int deleted = 0;   /// количество пропущенных элементов
int _index = 0;   /// позиция вставки в оригинальный вектор

for ( int i = 0 ; i < data.size()-deleted ; i++ )
{
   if ( _index >= indexes.size() ) break; /// Если все элементы удалены - заканчиваем
   if ( indexes[_index] !=i ) /// Если не нужно удалять то копируем в позицию internal 
        {
             data[internal] = data[ i ]; /// 
             internal++; /// смещаемся к незанятой позиции 


         } 
     else {
       _index++;   /// отбрасываем отработанный индекс
       /// Если копия необходима
       deleted ++;   /// инкрементируем счетчик удаленных
         }

}

if ( deleted  !=0 )
 data.erase(data.size()-deleted , deleted );  /// Укорачиваем "хвост" вектора
```

Answer (score 0):

Если нет желания писать эту удобную функцию самостоятельно, то можно воспользоваться одной из OS-библиотек, которые содержат массу полезных функций, упрощая жизнь разработчикам.

Например, решение с использованием [FunctionalPlus](https://github.com/Dobiasd/FunctionalPlus/) выглядит так:

```
#include <fplus/fplus.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<double> data {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
    std::vector<std::size_t> idxs {2,5};
    data = fplus::drop_idxs(idxs,data);
    for(const auto &x : data)
        std::cout<<x<<' ';
    std::cout<<'\n';
}
```